# Importing class in a nested folder

Tags: php, cakephp, import

I am using CakePHP 2.0 and trying to import a class file in my `app\Lib` folder. Using `App::Import('Lib','MyClass')` works fine if the `MyClass.php` file is directly under `app\Lib` folder.

But my directory structure is more organized, its more like `app\Lib\mypackage\folder`. I tried couple of approaches

1. I including this path in `bootstrap.php` by using `App::build`.
2. I used `App::Import('Lib','MyClass',array('file' => '/path/to/app/Lib/mypackage/folder/MyClass.php')`

Both the approaches didn't seem to help. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
App::import('Lib', 'package/folder/MyClass');
```